# How to update Progress Bar from download service when re-entering an Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service

I have activity A which contains a download button. When the download button is pressed, a progress bar appears and is updated as a file is downloaded. I use a service to download the file and use a `ResultReceiver` to update the UI.

```
new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
                super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
                if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
                    mBookAdapter.setDownloadProgress(book,
                            resultData.getInt("progress"));
                }
            }
```

The `setDownloadProgress` method has a call to `updateProgressView` to actually update the progress bar.

**updateProgressView**

```
public void updateProgressView(int position, int progress) {
                ((ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_book_download))
                        .setProgress(progress);
        }
```

The problem that I have is that if I exit from activity A while the download is running, and return to activity A the progress bar doesn't maintain the correct download status.

What is the best way to architecture my activity, service, etc., in order to update the progress bar even when I re-enter my activity?

I realize that I'm creating a new activity when I re-enter it, but my service likely references my old activity and any updates it does in the `ResultReceiver` is updating my old activity.

Comment: maybe somehow you can use Bind to service, or (IMO better) to use android DownloadManager class ?!

Comment: this  [link](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) describes using retained fragments I think it you need to use this technique